# Separar Nombres en SQL con condiciones

Tags: sql, datatables

Tengo una tabla en SQL de Nombres (Imagen Izquierda primera columna) la primera columna quiero Separar los apellidos y nombres de la siguiente forma (Imagen derecha 4 columnas) pero ahí también tengo nombres extranjeros que no tiene segundo apellido por ello lo rellanan con . y solo debería dar 1 nombre. adjunto nombres en conflicto
Adicionalmente los nombres compuestos con "DE" o "DE LA" que se una a uno solo y si tiene mas de 2 nombres todo agregarlo en la columna segundo nombre.

| Empleado |
| --- |
| ALVAREZ VASQUEZ WENDY GIOVANA |
| ZAVALA FALCON JASMIN DANIELA |
| INOCENTE RAMIREZ WALTER WILLELMO |
| . APARICIO JAVIER ALEJANDRO |
| . ARAY NUGLENIS ESTHER |
| BAUDIN . ROMAIN DAVID |
| FERREIRA . ANA CLAUDIA |
| - |
| ANAMPA DE LA CRUZ ALAN MICHAEL |
| ANASTACIO DE ALVARADO ARACELI AURORA |
| ANCCO HUAMAN NAGELY DE JESUS |
| ALVAREZ BARRIO DE MENDOZA ISOMI MAYLU |
| CAMARENA KOSTOVSKY ANGIE NAYRUSKA MARGARITA |
| ARNAO CHACALTANA DE PEREZ MARIA DEL ROSARIO |

[image: Referencia de Tabla Final]

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con personas con un solo nombre? ¿Qué pasa si tienen 3? ¿Qué pasa si tienen apellidos compuestos como De La Rosa? Tu ejemplo es fácil de solucionar, pero en la vida real se puede complicar mucho.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo agregare esos ejemplos para que nos ayuden

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la finalidad de separar así la data? Ahora, si así debe estar, porque no lo haces desde tu formulario de datos? pones cuantos `textbox` aceptes por cada cosa en tu DB... Al final sería hasta más accesible y amigable para tus usuarios finales.

Comment: lo que pasa es que yo exporto esa base de otra fuente y lo necesito trabajarlo en otras condiciones adicionales

Comment: ¿ANASTACIO DE ALVARADO son dos apellidos, pero CHACALTANA DE PEREZ es solo un apellido? ¿Porqué? No entiendo la regla. Es un nombre, entonces 'DE', entonces otro nombre. ¿Porqué son dos apellidos en un caso, pero solo uno en el otro?

Comment: Cuál es tu DBMS? Es muy importante etiquetar preguntas de SQL con el DBMS. Por ejemplo: Oracle tiene PL/SQL, una lenguaje de programación, en su DBMS, mientras MySQL y SQL Server no tienen nada semejante. Algunos DBMS tienen funcionas o operadores para expresiónes regulares, y otros no. Etc.